# Can't see image in sdcard when download it by using picasso

Tags: android

Sorry for my english is not good.
I have a problem, i download image from url by using picasso library, then store it in sdcard, but i can't see it in sdcard, and i only see it when i restart my phone, here is my code, what i do wrong??? help me, please !!!

```
public class Image extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_show_image);
    Intent it = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = it.getExtras();
    final String link = bundle.getString("link");
    final ImageView ivView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivView);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(link).into(ivView);
    Button btSetWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSetWallpaper);
    btSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadImage(link);
        }
    });
}
public void downloadImage(final String link){
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(link).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/abc.jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                        outputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                    e.getStackTrace();

                    }



                }
            });
            thread.start();
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Load Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Android Media Library that a media file has been added.

```
Intent intent =
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Replace the file with your saved file and it should appear in your Android Media Library without rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the system to run a media scanner and only then the file will appear in the gallery. Which can be done as follows:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
              Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

OR

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
          new String[] { filepath }, null,
          new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
         // your code here
      }
 });
```